# Awaiting EIC Decision

Tags: publications

I submitted an article 10 days ago. First at the dashboard, they put under review. After one week, the dashboard put Awaiting EIC Decision. Is that bad?

Comment: Could it be a “desk rejection” decision? Maybe. But I would say, stay positive and wait few more days. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that we can’t know. The status of the manuscript is exactly what it says on the tin - that it’s awaiting the decision of the EIC.

Trying to divine *why* is a bad idea. It’s possible that the original review notice was internal, not external. It’s possible the reviewers turned things around super quickly (my personal record is a single day). You can spin up a number of “just so” stories about the status.

Comment: What does EIC mean?

Comment: Editor-in-chief